# Как задать модель для шаблона?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть сайт на ASP.Net Core MVC. У него в шапке всегда есть выдвижной пункт меню со списком жанров, также там есть блок авторизованного пользователя (аватарка, ник, кнопка разлогина).

То есть, модель каждой View должна содержать в себе поле списка жанров и поле класса пользователя. Первое, что пришло мне в голову, это создание базового класса с этими полями, вроде этого:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    private ISession session;
    private TMDbContext context;

    public BaseViewModel(ISession session, TMDbContext context)
    {
        this.session = session;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public User CurrentUser => session?.GetJson<User>("CurrentUser");

    public IQueryable<Genre> Genres => context.Genres;
}
```

Но при попытке создать первый же производный класс и использовать его в контроллере сталкиваешься с некоторыми проблемами. Если сессию легко получить в каждом контроллере без каких-либо манипуляций из `HttpContext.Session`, то контекст у тебя в контроллере вообще не фигурирует явно. Все данные у меня идут через реализации интерфейсов (по рекомендации из учебника Фримена), с привязкой в `Startup.cs` типа 
`services.AddDbContext<TMDbContext>(option =>
                option.UseNpgsql(
                    Configuration["Data:Movies:ConnectionString"]));`

Поэтому выходит, что только ради работы шапки, мне будет необходимо запрашивать в конструкторе контроллера данные, которые будут выделяться из контекста, но нужны лишь для того, чтобы передать их в базовую ViewModel. 
Например, запрашивать жанры в `UserController`, который занимается регистрацией/авторизацией.

В связи со всем вышесказанным у меня возникает ощущение, что я мыслю не в том направлении и есть куда более правильное и элегантное решение.

Как и где делать привязку данных, которые нужны для шаблона, т.е. при отображении любой View?

[Класс связки данных с контекстом БД](https://pastebin.com/YxhGSEc5):

```
public interface IUserRepository
{

    IQueryable<User> Users { get; }

    IQueryable<UserRate> UserRates { get; }

    void SaveUser(User user);

    void SaveUserRate(UserRate userRate);

}

public class EFUserRepository : IUserRepository
{

    private TMDbContext context;

    public EFUserRepository(TMDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<User> Users => context.Users;

    public IQueryable<UserRate> UserRates => context.UserRates;

    public void SaveUser(User user)
    {
        context.Users.Add(user);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void SaveUserRate(UserRate userRate)
    {
        context.UserRates.Add(userRate);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

[Вызов этого класса в конструкторе контроллера](https://pastebin.com/Sss0sLEu):

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private IUserRepository repository;

    public UserController(IUserRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository; // в Startip.cs привязка через: services.AddTransient<IMovieRepository, EFMovieRepository>();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Для такой вещи отлично подойдет `ViewComponent` - считай самостоятельный кусок страницы со своей отдельной логикой реализуемой через отдельный класс. Поищите в книге главу про это.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, нет ничего плохого в том чтобы запросить жанры из вида минуя контроллер. Ведь контроллер - это компонент который обрабатывает пользовательский ввод (в случае веб-приложений - это HTTP-запросы), он не является почтальоном между моделями и видами.

*Важное замечание: когда я говорю "запросить" - я имею в виду запросить у репозитория, а не вытащить из базы. В представлении не должно быть ничего кроме логики отображения.*

В соответствии с [документацией](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection), для этого можно использовать директиву `@inject`:

```
@inject IGenresRepository Genres

<ul>
    @foreach (var genre in Genres.All) {
        <li>@genre.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Почему бы просто не вызвать через @Html.Action нужный метод контроллера? Есть какие-то дополнительные плюсы/минусы в этом случае? Ну, помимо "идём через дополнительный слой классов vs напрямую".

Comment: @AK так тоже можно - но появляются лишние сущности (контроллер). Не вижу смысла использовать его когда контроллер не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Основа MVC - это разделение отображения данных и логики получения данных.

Смотрите. У вас есть какой-то контроллер, например, FilmsController, в нём есть Action отображающий страницу детального описания фильма, скажем, Detail.

Правильный порядок действий в этом Action: считать всё из базы данных, наполнить модель данными, отключиться от базы, передать модель во View.

> За попытки залезть в базу данных из View или Model нужно расстреливать
>   на кодревью и заставлять тысячу раз писать мелом на доске "Смысл
>   MV*-паттернов в разделении кода бизнес-логики и отображения". Не надо
>   во вью или модели рассчитывать, что у вас есть доступ к базе на "щас
>   ещё чуть-чуть дочитаю", раньше надо было.

Поэтому ваша базовая модель, если вам реально ВЕЗДЕ нужен список жанров должна выглядеть так:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

Всё, наследуйтесь на здоровье.

И разумеется, у вас будет базовый контроллер, от которого вы будете наследовать каждый контроллер, в котором нужны будут жанры и в котором нужно прописать код получения жанров.

По-грамотному, каждый контроллер должен иметь в зависимостях те сервисы и репозитории, которые ему реально понадобятся для работы, а в зависимостях базового контроллера у вас будет ваш сервис жанров.

Но понятное дело, что гораздо проще обойтись вообще без сервисов и репозиториев, создавать в базовом контроллере контекст и пользоваться этим контекстом в каждом контроллере напрямую. Кодогенерация в Asp.Net MVC как раз содержит пример такого CRUD-контроллера.

Update. По поводу замечания Павла Майорова:

> Почему контроллер вообще должен знать что на странице есть шапка со
>   списком жанров? Шапка - это ответственность исключительно
>   представления, а не контроллера. Должна быть возможность сменить шапку
>   у сайта не переписывая все контроллеры!
>
> В общем, я считаю что выборка всех данных в контроллере нарушает SRP.

В принципе, можно сделать ещё более правильным образом.

Во-первых, создайте контроллер GenreController, пропишите нужный метод получения жанров и пометьте его атрибутом `[ChildActionOnly]`

Где-то в общем Layout страницы в div'е с шапкой страницы можете вставить показ списка жанров через  @Html.Action(метод, контроллер жанров).

Comment: Почему контроллер вообще должен знать что на странице есть шапка со списком жанров? Шапка  - это ответственность исключительно представления, а не контроллера. Должна быть возможность сменить шапку у сайта не переписывая **все** контроллеры!

Comment: В общем, я считаю что выборка всех данных в контроллере нарушает SRP.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Сценарий понятен, дописал в вопрос, что делать в данном случае.