# Модель ASP.NET Core 2.0 не передаётся в представление

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2

Начал осваивать ASP.NET Core. При попытке реализации простейшего приложения вылетает ошибка:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Контроллер:

```
[Route("")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        string[] files = {"wqew", "12232" };
        return View("~/Index.cshtml", files);
    }
}
```

Файл Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model string[]
@{

 }
<ul>
@foreach (string file in Model)
{
    <li>@file</li>
}
</ul>
```

Сразу при запуске сервера появляется вышеуказанная ошибка на этой строке:

```
@foreach (string file in Model)
```

Comment: А как создать и привязать вью к модели?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уберите строку @page и всё заработает.

Цитирую [доку по Razor](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio):

> Директива @page превращает файл в действие MVC, а значит обрабатывает
>   запросы напрямую, минуя контроллер.

Comment: можно ли считать это альтернативой статическим страницам?

Comment: @Anatol нет, на этих страницах можно выполнять код, так что это больше, чем статическая страница. Это можно считать альтернативой экшену без параметров, особенно если вы заинжектите во вью нужные репозитории/сервисы и делали экшены тонкими. [Подробнее тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790792/213987) Майоров писал, я что-то в последнее время подсел на этот способ.